# Как пересчитать существующие переменные?

Tags: java

Допустим есть несколько созданных переменных:

```
int a, b;
String b, d;
```

Как можно пересчитать их количество??

Comment: Если нужно получать количество, советую организовать массив. Напишите чего вы хотите добиться, возможно это можно сделать проще.

Comment: интересует, просто ли возможно такое, без каких то конкретных целей

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно посчитать поля класса при помощи getDeclaredFields(). Вот [пример](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/class_getdeclaredfields.htm). А вот локальные переменные, я вообще не уверен, что можно вообще как-то посчитать. Думаю, что не мудрствуя лукаво, действительно легче их все затолкать в массив, как предлогают в комментарии.

Comment: супер, то что надо